# how to increment a column value with 1 in a csv file

Tags: awk

I have a text file with 3 columns as below.

```
$ cat test.txt
1,A,300
1,B,300
1,C,300
```

Now i want to increment the third column only,
the output should be like below

```
1,A,300
1,B,301
1,C,302
```

Till now i have tried as,

```
awk -F, '{$3=$3+1;print}' OFS=, test.txt
```

But output is coming as,

```
1,A,301
1,B,301
1,C,301
```

Please do suggest, how to achieve the desired output?

Comment: or keep a separate variable for the amount to increment, and increment **that** variable for each line: `$3 += inc; inc++`

Answer (score 3):

Your initial approach with a small tweak:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { $3 += NR - 1; print }' test.txt
```

The `NR` variable holds the number of records (lines) read so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {offset=0; OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$3+offset++}"' /path/to/input
```

or, alternatively:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$3+(NR-1)}"' /path/to/input
```